# What is the probability that two people orginally seated at the two ends are no longer at the ends after sit down again?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification

> $7$ people are seated in a row . They all get up and sit down in random order.What is the probability that two people orginally seated at the two ends are no longer at the ends after sit down again ?

There are $7!$ arrangements for new siting without restriction. Moreover, for the numerator , $7!$ - the people  who were orginally in the ends are in the ends again. Then , $7! - 2!\times 5! =4800$

So ,answer is $4800/5040$

Am i correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not correct. While $ 7! - 2 \cdot 5! \ $ excludes seating arrangements where both of them are seated at two ends but it includes arrangements where one of them is seated at one of the ends.

So the correct probability will be,

$ \displaystyle \cfrac{5 \cdot4 \cdot 5!}{7!} = \cfrac{10}{21}$

We seat those two specific persons in two of the five seats and then arrange rest five persons in remaining seats in $5!$ ways.

Answer (score 0):

You can use probability directly to get a simpler solution.

$Pr = \dfrac57\cdot\dfrac46 = \dfrac{10}{21}$